# Errors while trying to compile with external libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have downloaded the [mimetic library](http://www.codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html#snippets) installation files,
and followed the INSTALL instructions.

```
./configure
```

a script that creates the make file after checking a series of things.

```
make
```

compiles the cpp files, after this different .o and .lo files appear in the original folder.

```
make install
```

seems to do a lot but the only thing that I seem to notice is that a mimetic directory
appears under /usr/local/include with all the header files.

than I try to compile the most simple main file possible:
(as offered in the library site : [original example](http://www.codesink.org/data/mimetic/t0.cc) )

```
#include <mimetic/mimetic.h>

using namespace mimetic;

int main()
{
    MimeEntity me;
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with following command ( on CentOS 5.7, gcc version : 4.1.2 ):

```
g++ mimetic.cpp
```

The error I get:

```
/tmp/ccWnsteO.o: In function `main':
mimetic.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `mimetic::MimeEntity::MimeEntity()'
mimetic.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `mimetic::MimeEntity::~MimeEntity()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From this I understand that the header files are found but the source/library itself 
is missing.

the MimeEntity constructor declaration appears in : /usr/local/include/mimetic/mimeentity.h
when I do a search for *mimeentity* I get the following :

```
/home/mimetic-0.9.7/mimetic/mimeentity.o
/home/mimetic-0.9.7/mimetic/mimeentity.h
/home/mimetic-0.9.7/mimetic/mimeentitylist.h
/home/mimetic-0.9.7/mimetic/mimeentity.cxx
/home/mimetic-0.9.7/mimetic/.libs/mimeentity.o
/home/mimetic-0.9.7/mimetic/mimeentity.lo
/home/mimetic-0.9.7/mimetic/.deps/mimeentity.Plo
/usr/local/include/mimetic/mimeentity.h
/usr/local/include/mimetic/mimeentitylist.h
```

I've tried with a search path to the libraries but the same error appears

```
g++ mimetic.cpp -L/home/mimetic-0.9.7/mimetic/
```

Something else strange is happening, when I try to compile the main mimetic.cpp file
with the line

```
MimeEntity me;
```

changed to

```
MimeEntity me();
```

it compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a linker error simply because you are not referencing the library when compiling the test source file. It needs to be something like:

```
g++ mimetic.cpp -l<libraryname>
```

The reason it compiles when you add the braces is that you are really declaring a function called 'me' that returns a MimeEntry. While it compiles, it does not do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are using to build your mimetic example seems incomplete. You are specifying library search patch (-L) but not the library itself.

1. Make sure that -L option specified the location of the mimetic library
2. Add -l'the-name-of-the-mimetic-library'. My guess would be -lmimetic
3. Add -I (that is capital i) option for the location of the headers.